# Using a variable for ComponentGroup/@Directory in WiX

Tags: wix

I have a WiX library project which contains several componentgroups similar to this

```
<ComponentGroup Id="CG_Group1" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Source="$(var.FilesLocation)">
  <Component Id="C_Group1_file1.file">
    <File Name="Group1_file1.file" Id="FI_Group1_file1.file" />
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

This library is shared by multiple WiX installer projects, and now i want the value of the `Directory` attribute of the `ComponentGroup` to be decided by the installer project referencing it.
What I have done in similar situations is to define WiX-variables in the installer projects like this

```
<WixVariable Id="FOLDERIDTOUSE" Value="SOMEID"/>
```

and referenced the variable from the wix library with

```
!(wix.FOLDERIDTOUSE)
```

However when doing this for the `Directory` attribute of the `ComponentGroup` I get an error

> The ComponentGroup/@Directory attribute's value, '!(wix.FOLDERIDTOUSE)', is not a legal identifier.  Identifiers may contain ASCII characters A-Z, a-z, digits, underscores (_), or periods (.).  Every identifier must begin with either a letter or an underscore.

Doesn't the `CompontentGroup/@Directory` support injection through wix-variables?

Is there another way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Edit:
This is what I'm trying to do:

In wix library:

```
<ComponentGroup Id="CG_Group1" Directory="!(wix.FOLDERIDTOUSE)" Source="$(var.FilesLocation)">
  <Component Id="C_Group1_file1.file">
    <File Name="Group1_file1.file" Id="FI_Group1_file1.file" />
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

In Installer Project(s):

```
<Directory Id="FOLDERSPECIFICTOTHISPROJECT" Name="MyFolder/>
<WixVariable Id="FOLDERIDTOUSE" Value="FOLDERSPECIFICTOTHISPROJECT"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Directories must be defined using the `<Directory>` tag since they get put into the Directory table of the msi. I believe that you are allowed to use a Directory AND a Property which have the same Id because they are treated as different things.

You should be able to use a wix variable during your build. Just need to use something like this

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Id="!(wix.FOLDERTOUSE)" />
</Directory>

...

<ComponentGroup Id="CG_Group1" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
    ...
</ComponentGroup>
```

Comment: The `<Directory>` element(s) is defined in multiple installer projects. I don't need to use a variable for them. The `<ComponentGroup>` element in question is however defined once in a library and it is in its `ComponentGroup/@Directory` attribute I'm trying to use the variable..